# Inspect method not doing what I expect

Tags: ruby

This is probably asked somewhere but I don't see it.

I am running script from a tutorial:

```rb
class Thing
        def set_name( aName )
            @name = aName
        end

        def get_name
            return @name
        end
end

class Treasure
      def initialize( aName, aDescription )
        @name         = aName
        @description  = aDescription
      end

      def to_s # override default to_s method
           "The #{@name} Treasure is #{@description}\n"
      end
end

thing1 = Thing.new
thing1.set_name( "A lovely Thing" )
puts thing1.get_name


t1 = Treasure.new("Sword", "an Elvish weapon forged of gold")
t2 = Treasure.new("Ring", "a magic ring of great power")
puts t1.to_s
puts t2.to_s
# The inspect method lets you look inside an object
puts "Inspecting thing: #{thing1.inspect}"
puts "Inspecting 1st treasure: #{t1.inspect}"
```

but when I run it it returns

```
The Sword Treasure is an Elvish weapon forged of gold
The Ring Treasure is a magic ring of great power
Inspecting thing: #<Thing:0x0000000003186c00 @name="A lovely Thing">
Inspecting 1st treasure: #<Treasure:0x0000000003186b10 @name="Sword", @description="an Elvish weapon forged of gold">
```

when I'm expecting this:

```
The Sword Treasure is an Elvish weapon forged of gold
The Ring Treasure is a magic ring of great power
Inspecting thing: #<Thing:0x0000000003186c00 @name="A lovely Thing">
Inspecting 1st treasure: The Sword Treasure is an Elvish weapon forged of gold
```

I am running Ruby version, 2.4.0

What am I missing to have it return what I expect.

Comment: You're not overriding `#inspect`. Why do you expect this output?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your question title is "Inspect override not doing what I expect", and then you show a lot of completely irrelevant code and leave out the *one part* that is actually relevant: the place where you override `inspect`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: yes there is a lot of irrelevant code directly to the question. I just didn't want to have it be that the question had no context. It was a matter of do I add irreverent code to the direct question or, do I have no context and simply have some stuff about treasure and elvish weapons which I felt was even less helpful without the respective classes to give context.

and the answer I needed was to add `def inspect` as was given by @mrzasa in their reply.

Comment: Also I'll add I'm not familiar with Ruby enough to tell what was needed for sure. I am more familiar with Python.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: in the tutorial I was following that is the output that is shown.
Obvously Ruby has changed in since the tutorial was written.

Comment: @WhitequillRiclo: that tutorial must be for ruby 1.8. That's 10+ years old. There should be newer ones :)

Comment: that is okay with me because I'm using RPG Maker VX Ace which has Ruby 1.9.2 built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#to_s` and `#inspect` are separate methods. If you want to change an output of `Treasure#inspect`, override `#inspect`:

```
class Treasure
      def initialize( aName, aDescription )
        @name         = aName
        @description  = aDescription
      end

      def to_s # override default to_s method
           "The #{@name} Treasure is #{@description}\n"
      end
end
```

or use `#to_s` in inspect:

```
class Treasure
      def initialize( aName, aDescription )
        @name         = aName
        @description  = aDescription
      end

      def to_s # override default to_s method
        "The #{@name} Treasure is #{@description}\n"
      end

      def inspect
         to_s
      end
end
```

Worth reading:

- https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/12/ruby-inspect-method/
- https://medium.com/rubycademy/display-complex-objects-d897be936ae0

Comment: Thank you. That worked. the tutorial doesn't show that. It must be a slightly different version of Ruby that the instructor is using.